# Responsive SVG background image

Tags: html, css

I have a landing page using the following pattern:

```
<main>
  <section>Section A</section>
  <section>Section B</section>
  <section>Section C</section>
  <section>Section D</section>
</main>
```

It's a long page that you can scroll and that will include some animations. My problem is the following: I have an SVG background image spreading across Section B and C that needs to scale to a certain percentage, and also to be at a certain position.

My approach so far has been to set the background image on `<main>` with the following code:

```
main {
  background-image: url('/path/to/image.svg');
  background-position: 40% 76%;
  background-size: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: border-box;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

But it comes with 2 main problems:

1. First, I have to position my background image from the start of `<main>` even though I really only starts at "Section B"
2. Second, which is the biggest problem, I can place my image absolutely with background position as I did above, but it scales very poorly. My image is either not at a proper position nor at a proper scale.

EDIT: Sandbox link here https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-frost-ste6y

Comment: The first problem is very easy to solve by wrapping both sections into a `<div>` and setting background on it. With the second problem, it is not really possible to answer without seeing what is wrong, preferably on working code.

Comment: @Theo, you could use a Pseudo selector on `Section B`, set the svg as the background of the `before` element for B.

Comment: Great idea @iamcastelli!

Comment: @LáďaDurchánek what do you want me to post ? :)

Comment: @ThéoLavaux Preferably a sandbox link where we can see the issue :)

Comment: Is the image able to go through the other section though with a pseudo selector ? I'm using didn't mention that I'm using Nuxt.js and I have scoped scss

Comment: It is, but you can't set its dimensions relative to both sections, that's why I suggested the extra wrapper div.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I'm creating a sandbox to reproduce my problem

Comment: Looking at your `First, I have to position my background image from the start of <main> even though I really only starts at "Section B"`. If it really starts at B, why not use the svg as a background image on B itselft(pseudo selector would do too, BUT), then position it in such a way that it spans to the next section. `overflow-hidden of course`.

Right now, it hard to tell what problem your image is giving you. Could you share you svg file on something like `https://svgur.com/` so we can play around it with a repro. Or better yet, send a repro showing your issue?

Comment: Sandbox would be great

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-frost-ste6y

Comment: The SVG image is supposed to be at a certain position related to the sections content, as for the white text for example.